# What's the meaning of `user-interface vty 0 4`?

Tags: router

In the Quidway `AR 2220` router.

What's the meaning of `user-interface vty 0 4` and `user-interface vty 16 20`?

```
[R4-ui-console0]display this 
[V200R003C00]
#
user-interface con 0
 authentication-mode password
 set authentication password cipher %$%$tY:3;1jinGR3)cL'0HKL,.!:&Q:eJ]R-P!'maq*K
jNNB.!=,%$%$
idle-timeout 20 0
user-interface vty 0 4
user-interface vty 16 20
#
return
```

Answer (score 2):

When I google "Quidway user-interface vty" then the first result gives me [this site](http://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000017269?section=j006):

> The Virtual Type Terminal (VTY) manages and monitors users who log in to the device using VTY user interfaces. When a user's terminal connects to the device using Telnet or Secure Shell (SSH), a VTY is set up. S2700 switches (except S2710SI, S2700-52P-EI, and S2700-52P-PWR-EI) support a maximum of 8 concurrent users, and other models support a maximum of 15 concurrent users.

"Concurrent users" connect to different virtual lines. The numbers (`0 4` and `16 20`) indicite virtual lines. Lines 0–4 means five virtual lines. The same goes for lines 16–20.